# Code Igniter Composer Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter-2, composer-php, autoload

Could somebody please explain to me how to integrate Twitter Bootstrap in Codeingniter 2.14 via Composer? I've included composer's autoloader into index.php like so:

```
/************ COMPOSER AUTOLOADER *******************/
include_once FCPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php';

//codeignirer autoloader
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

And twitter bootstrap is obviously in the vendor folder.How can I access it in my view properly.Would be really grateful.

Comment: You don't need composer for that, just drop the css/js folder among your other assets and you're set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

structure you application like this

```
myapp/
    assets/
          /js
          /css
          /images
    application/
    system/
```

Now put the twitter js and css files in the js and css in assets of codeigniter

Then access them like this in your view file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery.js')?>"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/style.css')?>" />

<img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/abc_image.png')?>" alt="" />
```

Comment: Not sure if I have to post a new question, but is a yes or no directly related to this: Is a bad practice to load assets directly from "vendor"?